# Thread Safety using final

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, thread-safety, final

Here is an example method for explaining thread safety:

```
class Counter {
    private int counter = 0;

    public void increment() {
        counter++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

In order to provide thread safety, there are several methods and I would prefer using `AtomicInteger` approach. However;

**1.** I am also wondering if I can provide thread safe by using `final` for the necessary variable(s). If so, how can I perform this?

**2.** Is one of the reason using `final` commonly in Java for variables and method arguments to provide thread safety?

Comment: Using final on what? Because using it on counter means counter doesn't change.

Comment: You can take a look at [jls17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I am also wondering if I can provide thread safe by using final for the necessary variable(s). If so, how can I perform this?

Here is a complete implementation of your `Counter` class, using `AtomicInteger`:

```
class Counter {
    // counter must be final here:
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public void increment() {
        counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return counter.get();
    }
}
```

Note that `counter` is `final`. This means that the reference can not be updated but the referenced `AtomicInteger` can. In addition, we get a guarantee regarding how `Counter` can be used across threads:

The relevant passage from [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> The usage model for final fields is a simple one: Set the final fields for an object in that object's constructor; and do not write a reference to the object being constructed in a place where another thread can see it before the object's constructor is finished. If this is followed, then when the object is seen by another thread, that thread will always see the correctly constructed version of that object's final fields. It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

The converse is also true: If a field is not final, you are not guaranteed to see the correctly constructed version of the object, even if the constructor has finished running.
In our example, this means that we might get a `NullPointerException` if we call `getValue()` or `increment()` from another thread, since that thread might read `counter` as `null`.

> 2. Is one of the reason using final commonly in Java for variables and method arguments to provide thread safety?

Only for field variables. `final` provides guarantees for fields but not for local variables and method parameters.

Comment: You are completely forgetting that the reference to the Counter still needs to make use of safe publication otherwise you have a data race on your hands. And because of the safe publication of that reference, all modifications to that object till that point, will be visible to the other threads due to a combination of program order rule with volatile variable or monitor object rule. So this covers all fields including the non-final fields. Otherwise, you would for example not be able to safely share a regular POJO (no synchronization) through e.g. blocking queue.

Comment: And because you need that safe publication of the reference to the Counter, the NPE can't happen because of the guaranteed happens-before edge between constructing the object in 1 thread and using it in another. Therefore it isn't needed to make the counter field final.

Comment: It depends on the way we publish `Counter` if there is a guaranteed happens-before edge. Using `final` lets us safely use double-checked locking, where we either (safely) publish the object via a race or under a lock. Only the lock guarantees happens-before.

Comment: This post explains how to do safe double-checked locking via `final`: https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication

Answer (score 0):

In properly synchronized code, the final isn't needed.

E.g. if you would use:

```
class MyCounter{
    private AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger();

    public int inc(){return c.incrementAndGet();}

    public int get(){return c.get();}
}
```

And you would share the MyCounter-instance with another thread, you need to make sure that there is a happens-before edge between writing c and reading c. This can be done in various ways e.g. you pass the MyCounter-instance to the constructor of some thread (thread start rule). Or you pass it through a volatile field (volatile variable rule) or a synchronized block (monitor lock rule).

This is typically called 'safe publication' and for a correctly synchronized system, this is all you need. If you don't pass the reference safely, you have a data race and weird problems can happen like seeing a partially constructed object. Therefore there is a second mechanism called initialization safety; so no matter if the reference to an object isn't published safely, initialization safety using final will act as a backup solution. The primary use-case for this AFAIK is security.

So for correctly synchronized code, there is no need for final.

That doesn't mean that you should not add finals. It has all kinds of benefits like no accidental changes and it is pretty informative. So I prefer to make as many fields final as possible.

Final has no meaning for method arguments from a memory model perspective, since they are private to a thread. Only shared memory needs to be dealt with in a memory model. Making arguments of a method final is a flavor issue. Some people want it, others don't. I'm not crazy about long method signatures and tend not to add them unless I'm writing some difficult code. But I would be fine if local variables and formal arguments would be final by default (like Rust).

Comment: This answer is not correct. `final` is explicitly mentioned as part of the memory model in the Java Language Specification. In this situation, making `c` `final` guarantees safe publication.

Comment: @JørgenFogh I suggest you should spend some more time reading the answer or studying the specification. The reference to the MyCounter class should be safely published because otherwise, you have a data race on your hands on that reference. And because of that external safe publication, there will be a happens-before edge on the 'c' field and hence it will not suffer from a data race.

Comment: You're right, your answer is correct and I should have read it more carefully.

Answer (score -1):

No, the `final` keyword doesn't have anything in common with thread safety.

The `final` keyword on variables makes them immutable, you can't change their value anymore.
However, it's not like the `const` keyword in c++ where the whole variable content cannot change. In Java only the reference is immutable.

```
   final AtomicReference<String> toto = new AtomicReference<>("text");
   toto.set("new text"); // totally fine
   toto = new AtomicReference<>("text"); // does not compile, as toto is immutable reference.
```

But, there is another keyword that fulfill what you are looking for. It's `volatile`. https://www.baeldung.com/java-volatile

In short, the value change on all thread simultaneously and is available immediately.
That's what is used in all the `Atomic*` Java classes.

Ex. https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java

Comment: But there are some examples using `final` to make variables immutable and perform thread safety with this. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the [final keyword does receive special treatment by the memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) to convey the guarantee that final variables are perceived as fully initialized even if the object is shared through a data race. Granted, that's not often useful, and isn't useful for OP's problem, but it means that final can affect thread safety.

Answer (score -1):

I m just gonna add this with Erwan Daniel's answer .
Your
If you want a  counter shared between all your Threads here is another version of your code.

```
 class SharedCounter {
  private AtomicInteger sharedCounter ;
  
  public Counter(){
   this.sharedCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
  }

  public void increment() {
     sharedCounter.getAndIncrement();
  }

  public int value() {
     return sharedCounter.get();
  }
```

The final will prevent your `atomicInteger12` from changing the object it's using **And** you can freely set it's value.

```
final SharedCounter atomicInteger12 = new Counter() ;
```

Comment: `sharedCounter` needs to be `final` as well to guarantee safe publication. Otherwise, another thread might throw a `NullPointerException` before the field has been initialized. It is simpler not to wrap `AtomicInteger` in the first place.

Comment: @JørgenFogh your comment is incorrect. If you have a data-race on the reference of the SharedCounter, then an external thread can see a partly constructed object. But in this case the atomicInteger12 is final and therefor there is no data race and as a consequence the NPE can't happen.